# How to solve SharePoint Server Error?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

[image: Unable to find the specified error care to help]

I am having trouble opening the **Site Actions> Site Permissions** link on one web app  and i have confirmed that the i have the account has all the permissions including SQL permissions and SharePoint farm permission with the account that i am using

Comment: did you check the ULS logs and Event Log for more clue, which file it is complaining.

Comment: How you accessing your site collection, Servername:portnumber or FQDN?http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2010/10/13/file-not-found-error-when-going-to-site-settings-of-subsite/

Comment: Hi Wagas, I am using FQDN  to access the site collection the Logs doesnt really show anything more details about this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please, verify the URL in the browser as you access this page. There is a condition in `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WebAdminPageBase` class of  that throws this exception is onload method:

```
if (!WebAdminPageBase.IsLayoutFolderInTheWeb(this.Web.ServerRelativeUrl))
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
```

The `IsLayoutFolderInTheWeb` method is defined as:

```
public static bool IsLayoutFolderInTheWeb(string strServerRelativeWebUrl)
{
  string str = SPHttpUtility.UrlPathDecode(SPUtility.OriginalServerRelativeRequestUrl, false).ToLower();
  int length = str.IndexOf("/_layouts/");
  return length > 0 && strServerRelativeWebUrl.ToLower() == str.Substring(0, length) || length == 0 && strServerRelativeWebUrl == "/";
}
```